# insert text .before() INSIDE the tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, insert

here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>All this content, including the HTML comes from a CMS</p>
</div>
```

I want to insert some more content from the CMS like so

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Greetings</h2>
  <p>NEW YORK - December 29, 2010 - All this content, including the HTML comes from a CMS</p>
</div>
```

This tag won't work, as it'll put it before the

tag...

```
$('.container p').before('NEW YORK - December 29, 2010');
```

so how can i insert it into the tag? I can't tag that p with a class or put a marker inside the

tag since it is being spit out of a CMS.

Comment: why don't you wrap your p tag with div tag, maybe you can handle it easier?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the prepend(), which seems to do what I want. That is another solution as well. Thanks!! http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: correct, go with something like this - $("p").prepend("NEW YORK - December 29, 2010 - ");

Answer (score 4):

Use text().

```
var oldText = $('.container p').text();
$('.container p').text("NEW YORK - December 29: " + oldtext);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.container p').text(function(i,v) {
    return "NEW YORK - December 29: " + v;
});
```